# ListView filtering without custom filter

Tags: android, listview, filter

I got code for filter listview as follow. But it is not considering middle words.
Can I filter by containing words without custom filter.

```
ListView listView;

String[] from = { "php_key","c_key","android_key","hacking_key" };

ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.zone_list); 

arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.setlanguage, R.id.tvName, from);

listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer . First search in array then setAdapter .

```
       ListView listView;

    String[] from = { "php_key","c_key","android_key","hacking_key" };

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.zone_list); 

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.setlanguage, R.id.tvName, from);

If(from.contains("search text")){

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```